# Changing Fonts in Rails 4 don't Work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-4

On localhost eveything show's up fine. But on deployment Heroku doesn't get the Font right.
Here's how it should look like ->

[image]

**and here is how it looks on Heroku** -> [Project on Heroku](http://flatx.herokuapp.com/flatuipro_demo/index)

Github Repo -> **[Here](https://github.com/Theminijohn/flat-working)**

The font is declared in **app/assets/stylesheets/flat-ui.css**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Rails doesn't recognize this automatically, but got it working by including in my application.html.erb file

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```